# How to call a single argument from a function with multiple argument in C?

Tags: c

Say you have a several function like this:

```
void Inventory(int index, char input[], int qty)

void AddItem(){
     int index = Inventory(index);
     if (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
          ...
     }
}
```

But it gave me an error 'A value of type "Void" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"'

Can someone explain to me in detail since im new to programming too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to initialize `index` as an `int` whose value is returned by calling `Inventory(index)`. But the `Inventory` function you provided has a return type of `void`, not the expected `int`, so there's no way to get that value.

Also, your call to `Inventory` is missing an argument to the `chat input[]` and `int qty` parameters. Additionally, `index` is uninitialized at the time that you're trying to use it (within the definition of `index`).

Comment: @Clifford Haha yeah, that doesn't help, does it? :p

Answer (score 2):

The function `Inventory` does not return anything (which is `void`) and you are trying to affect 'nothing' to a variable of type `int`. That's why the compiler is complaining.

The solution is to have your `Inventory` function return an `int` value instead of `void`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question and code snippet that you have provided are misleading.

Secondly, You are getting this error because the return type of function Inventory is Void, which means it returns nothing. And you are trying to assign nothing to variable index, which is of type int.

And, if you are trying to call multi-argument function without having to pass all arguments, make rest of the argument optional.

Answer (score 0):

1. void foo(/*...*/) means that the function foo does not return anything. So you cant assign nothing to something.
2. In C you need to pass all the parameters. In other languages (like C++) some parameters might have default values and you do not have to pass them when call the function. But it is not possible in the C language and you need to pass all the parameters (arguments)